# Javascript how to compare two strings

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is the Javascript Function. Please Explain How to compare two string in Javascript.

```
   <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
/*javascript function*/ 
    function ajax(str)
    {
    if (str.length==0)
      {
      document.getElementById("res").innerHTML="";    
      return;
      }
      if(str=="Select City")
      {
      alert("Please Select a City");
      }
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML=="";
    var url="code1.php?q="+str+"&r"+Math.random();
    var obj;
    try{
    obj=new ActiveXObject(Microsoft.XMLHTTP);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        try
        {
        obj=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e)
        {
        alert("Your browser not suport ajax");
        }
    }
    obj.open('Get',url,true);
    obj.send(null);
    obj.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if(obj.readyState==4)
    {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML=obj.responseText;
    }
    }
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <select onchange="ajax(this.value)" name="sel" id="btn"><option>Dharmashala</option><option>Manali</option><option>Shimla</option></select>
    <div id="res"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But it does not work please suggest me a proper method to do this.

Comment: Does it throw an error, give incorrect results, etc?  Can you say more than "it doesn't work?"

Comment: What does not work? Try using Firebug or one of the browser's built in debuggers to check your code.

Comment: no errors it showing i am confused that is it correct way to compare?

Comment: sidenote: always put those `{`on the same line with it's according statement, as this prevents the js-engines from erroneous parsing. e.g.
`return<br>
{
...
}`is not the same like
`return{
...
}` as the first on returns undefined, the second one `...`

Comment: if(str=="Select City")
      {
      alert("Please Select a City");
      }
i am talking about this code...

Comment: You are doing the string comparison correctly. However, str is never equal to "Select City". The only values passed into this function are the option values Dharmashala, Manali and Shimla.

Comment: You are making a correct string comparison, but the value will never be "Select City" since you don't have an option with that value.

Comment: Yes, that's a string comparison. Still, your ajax function is never called with "Selct City" as an argument, so what do you exspect?

Comment: Uh, we seem to agree about that one :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's not working because you have your `this` context incorrect. `this.value` is trying to call the `value` of your `select` element instead of the selected `option`. Try this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  var select = document.getElementById('btn');
  var selected = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
}, false);
window.addEventListener('change', function(selected) { changeHandler(selected); }, false);

function changeHandler(selected) {
  // run your ajax() function
}
```

Also, be sure to put a `value` on each of your `option` elements.

Answer (score 5):

`===` for string comparison

```
if(str === "Select City") {
    alert("Please Select a City");`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How to compare strings in JavaScript? Use the `==` operator for equivalence and `>`/`<` for alphabetical difference.

In your code, this line seems to be a bit useless:

```
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML=="";
```

Don't you want an assignment here (`=`)?